# Detect a change in array of booleans binded on buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a collection of 7 Yes/No buttons. So i made an array of booleans to use with that buttons. I use MVVM in WPF

[image]

My Xaml of one of those buttons looks like this.

```xml
<telerik:RadRadioButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding ListYesNoButtons[0],Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{x:Static Properties:Resources.DlgSafetyCoach_Yes}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<telerik:RadRadioButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding ListYesNoButtons[!0],Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{x:Static Properties:Resources.DlgSafetyCoach_No}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

I fill my array with properties i need to from a database. OnPageEnter()

```cs
ListYesNoButtons = new bool[7]{Item.ProcessedItem.TimePersonCheck, Item.ProcessedItem.AnnoncedSafetyCheck,
                Item.ProcessedItem.SafetyDescriptionCheck, Item.ProcessedItem.ToldPerson,
                Item.ProcessedItem.BalancePartners, Item.ProcessedItem.CheckSafety, Item.ProcessedItem.Positif};

RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListYesNoButtons);
```

So to get and set those values i wrote this get/set

```cs
#region ListYesNoButtons
        private bool[] _listYesNoButtons;
        public bool[] ListYesNoButtons
        {
            get { return _listYesNoButtons; }
            set
            {
                if (_listYesNoButtons == value)
                    return;
                _listYesNoButtons = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListYesNoButtons);
            }
        }
#endregion
```

The problem is, when i change the state of one of those buttons. the change is not detected and thus not updated when you click yes/no,
but when i submit the form. The values are correct.

My DoOk method looks like this.

```cs
Item.ProcessedItem.TimePersonCheck = ListYesNoButtons[0];
Item.ProcessedItem.AnnoncedSafetyCheck = ListYesNoButtons[1];
Item.ProcessedItem.SafetyDescriptionCheck = ListYesNoButtons[2];
Item.ProcessedItem.ToldPerson = ListYesNoButtons[3];
Item.ProcessedItem.BalancePartners = ListYesNoButtons[4];
Item.ProcessedItem.CheckSafety = ListYesNoButtons[5];
Item.ProcessedItem.Positif = ListYesNoButtons[6];
```

I need to trigger the set when one of those values are changed in the array. How do i implement it here in my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your Raise Property change is wired only at the Collection level. So if you re-initialize the main bool[] collection, then only the RaisePropertyChange happens.

There is no code where you are triggering the property change for Each Index. Instead of bool[]  use:

```
System.Collections.ComponentModel.ObservableCollection<bool>
```

That collection takes care of RaisePropertyChange per item per update.

Comment: i changed my bool[] but it my breakpoint still not triggers when i change the sate of 1 button

Comment: Which Breakpoint are you expecting to hit? The setter of ListYesNoButtons?? That will happen only once when you assign/initialize the Collection. It wont hit per Index change.

Comment: i thought everytime i change a button state that it will update the value in that collection

Comment: ow yeah i just attached a textbox IsEnabled prop on the state of a button. It works, my bad :)